# Check if value is a substring in at least of of many strings

Tags: excel, search, substring

i have a column A with strings:

apple

orange

grape

now i have a second column C with many strings:

apples are red

i hate people

squeeze the orange

rotten flesh

clean towels

in column B, i want to put TRUE next to the strings in column A **that are substrings of ANY of the strings in column C**.

So in this case column B should have:

TRUE

TRUE

FALSE

I looked at this formula on exceljet but not what i'm looking for:

https://exceljet.net/formula/range-contains-one-of-many-substrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B1 put:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("*"&A1&"*",C:C,0))
```

And copy down

[image]